# SQL Cartesian Product / Cross Join direction

Tags: mysql, cartesian-product, cross-join

I have two simple tables for this subject:

```
   abc       numbers
+--------+ +--------+
| letter | | number |
+--------+ +--------+
| a      | |      1 |
| b      | |      2 |
+--------+ |      3 |
           +--------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT letter, number
FROM abc
CROSS JOIN numbers;
```

Result:

```
+--------+--------+
| letter | number |
+--------+--------+
| a      |      1 |
| b      |      1 |
| a      |      2 |
| b      |      2 |
| a      |      3 |
| b      |      3 |
+--------+--------+
```

Expected result:

```
+--------+--------+
| letter | number |
+--------+--------+
| a      |      1 |
| a      |      2 |
| a      |      3 |
| b      |      1 |
| b      |      2 |
| b      |      3 |
+--------+--------+
```

Why did it not come out as I expected?

From what I have read about cartesian products in this [article](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CartesianJoin) it should've come out as I expected.

[image]

Can anyone explain step by step how the result I got was processed by MySql?

Comment: Looks like nested loops with numbers as the outer table. No order is guaranteed without order by.

Comment: Because sets by definition are unordered unless explicitly ordered. The answer to your question can probably only be found by examining the source code that makes up the MySQL engine, specifically the query processor and related optimizers. In the end, does it matter why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result sets are the same.  SQL result sets have no ordering, unless you specify an `order by`.  Both contain the same rows, so they are the same.

If you expect a query to return rows in a particular order and you do not use an `order by`, then your expectation is simply wrong.

Comment: I am going to post another question in a bit, somewhat related to this.